# I have custom annotation @DTO that transform body from dto to entity however swagger takes the entity to create parameters not DTOs

Tags: java, swagger

Here is my controller request

```
 @PostMapping("/requestApproval")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> requestApproval(@DTO(TripIdDTO.class)  Trip requestingApprovalTrip) {
        this.tripService.requestApproval(requestingApprovalTrip);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new MessageResponse("Trip status has been changed to WAITING_FOR_APPROVAL!"));
    }
```

The annotation takes the request body from JSON format, converts it into DTO and than into the `Trip` entity type.

Swagger generates the parameters using the fields of the Trip entity. Is there a way to customize swagger to use the `TripIdDTO` class to create the parameters for the documentation isntead of `Trip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the project doesn't obey the usual contract between Swagger and Spring Boot, some additional settings should be done to make it work as wish.

#### Step 1 Register the real API model

```java
@Configuration
// Only need for swagger 2.9.2
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    TypeResolver resolver = new TypeResolver();

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build().additionalModels(resolver.resolve(MessageDto.class));
  }
}
```

#### Step 2 Tell Swagger the real API model used

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/message",
      produces = {"application/json;charset=utf-8"},
      consumes = {"application/json;charset=utf-8"},
      method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ApiImplicitParams({
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "request", required = true,
          dataType = "MessageDto", paramType = "body")
  })
  ResponseEntity<?> createMessage(Message message) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

By doing this, we declare a param with the type `MessageDto` and should be fetched from the HTTP request body.

#### Step 3 Tell Swagger to ignore the existed params

```java
@Data
public class Message {

  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
  private Integer code = null;

  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
  private String message = null;
}
```

The `Message` class has two filed with public `get` methods(I think it's also your case). Since there is no `@RequestBody` besides `Message`, Swagger will treat all fields of `Message` as query params. To make these useless parts invisible in the API doc, we should mark them as hidden.

#### P.S.

This function works properly in Swagger 2.9.2, and not work in 3.0.0. It is a bug and this needs some time to get fixed I guess. You can find more information in [springfox issue #3435](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3435).

All the codes can be found at [this repo - swagger demo](https://github.com/LangInteger/spring-boot-test/blob/main/docs/swagger-test.md).